# Dynamically Create upload image box and preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a page where I can upload different images.

I want them to see 1 box and when they upload a file the preview will display there.

At page load I want to display only 1 box, after he chooses a file, I would like to display another box where he can upload an image and see the preview.

HTML

```
<script class="jsbin" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<div class="image-upload-wrap">
<input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" 
 accept="image/*" />
<div class="drag-text">
  <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="file-upload-content">
<img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
<div class="image-title-wrap">
  <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove- 
 image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="file-upload">

  <div class="image-upload-wrap">
  <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" 
   accept="image/*" />
   <div class="drag-text">
    <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="file-upload-content">
<img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
<div class="image-title-wrap">
  <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove- 
   image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
</div>
```

```
<div class="image-upload-wrap">
<input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" 
 accept="image/*" />
<div class="drag-text">
  <h3>Drag and drop a file or select add Image</h3>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-upload-content">
  <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <div class="image-title-wrap">
  <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove- 
   image">Remove <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span></button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.file-upload {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.file-upload-btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1FB264;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #15824B;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.file-upload-btn:hover {
  background: #1AA059;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.file-upload-btn:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.file-upload-content {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.file-upload-input {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-upload-wrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 4px dashed #1FB264;
  position: relative;
}

.image-dropping,
.image-upload-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #1FB264;
  border: 4px dashed #ffffff;
}

.image-title-wrap {
  padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
  color: #222;
}

.drag-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.drag-text h3 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #15824B;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.file-upload-image {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.remove-image {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #cd4535;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #b02818;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.remove-image:hover {
  background: #c13b2a;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-image:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.image-upload-wrap').hide();

      $('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('.file-upload-content').show();

      $('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  } else {
    removeUpload();
  }
}

function removeUpload() {
  $('.file-upload-input').replaceWith($('.file-upload-input').clone());
  $('.file-upload-content').hide();
  $('.image-upload-wrap').show();
}
$('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragover', function () {
        $('.image-upload-wrap').addClass('image-dropping');
    });
    $('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragleave', function () {
        $('.image-upload-wrap').removeClass('image-dropping');
});
```

Here is the code in a codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRgBJw

I have 3 boxes right now which all show at the same time.I would like to show only 1 in the begging and then show 1 by 1 after user chooses/uploads a photo. But when I upload a file it shows the preview on all 3 boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how the classes work .. Code append anything to the elements with the same class .. so you need to have a reference to get just `$(this)` input elements

```
function readURL(input) {
  var Thisinput = $(input); // <<<< this input
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      Thisinput.closest('.file-upload').find('.image-upload-wrap').hide(); //<<< get the image-upload-wrap element for this input .. same with the next elements

      Thisinput.closest('.file-upload').find('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
      Thisinput.closest('.file-upload').find('.file-upload-content').show();

      Thisinput.closest('.file-upload').find('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  } else {
    removeUpload();
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BvpyyE)

Do the same thing with `removeUpload()` function .. But something to take in consider .. you'll need to add argument like `function removeupload(input)` and in html `removeupload(this)`

[Codepen with both functions updated](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XopJqz)

Comment: This worked pretty well! I did the same thing for removeUpload() but no luck..I updated the codepen.

Comment: glad to hear that @JRowzer .. you still has a little bit of work with your `removeupload()` function .. and something to take in consider .. you'll need to add argument like `function removeupload(input)` and in html `removeupload(this)` .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: I have added removeupload(input) and removeupload(this) in html but still can't get it to work for some reason. I have tried with some other combinations. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @JRowzer just add the line `var Thisinput = $(input); // <<<< this input` on the top of the `removeupload(input)` function

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about that line...Now it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: By any chance, do you know how I can make it so it shows only the first image upload box, and after I choose an image the second one will appear and so on?

Comment: @JRowzer simple is that [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzdwzG) .. explanation: add class `.hidden` to css with `display: none` and set the hidden class for the `file-upload` element but not the first one .. then on the readURL function you can check if the `file-upload` has a next `file-upload` with hidden if so just remove the `hidden` class from it (show it) :-)

Comment: Hmmm it makes a lot of sense! It works great in the codepen. But I tried it with my actual code but it doesnt work =/ .  Actual code looks like this. : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLREzL

Comment: don't make it difficult .. make everything easy to be easy .. just arrange what you're want to do .. 1st: to show one after one you need to hide all the elements but not the first one .. 2nd: on change the first input *while you have `readURL` already on change event so we can add the code to it* check if another hidden element next to it .. if yes show it .. simple :)

Comment: Well the file-upload is hidden on start except the first one. Do I need to also hide the sections and bootstrap columns? If I expect element and manual remove the hidden class it is working.

Comment: @JRowzer chagne  `Thisinput.closest('.file-upload').next('.file-upload.hidden')` with `$('.file-upload.hidden:first')` .. no need for `.next()` while the next `file-upload` is not in the same level .. you can just pick the first hidden one by using  `$('.file-upload.hidden:first')`

Comment: @JRowzer but it works for me .. you just need to play around styling [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdNXGz)

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to change the second one as welll...Is it possible to put the class back to hidden for the others if they remove it the image?

Comment: Sorry @JRowzer but I helped you as I can.. Have a great day :-)